# Mysql Percentage According to Group

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, percentage

There is a table like a bottom.

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| type  | ip      | line     | count |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
| x     | 1       | EN       | 10    |
| x     | 1       | FR       | 10    |
| x     | 2       | EN       | 5     |
| x     | 5       | EN       | 5     |
| y     | 3       | CH       | 10    |
| y     | 3       | PT       | 10    |
| y     | 4       | PT       | 10    |
| y     | 6       | EN       | 10    |
+-------+---------+----------+-------+
```

I am trying to calculate percentage of lines according to ip's which inside types. Actually count don't use for calculate the percentage, i only looking number of specific line and divide it total number of line. So, i desire to see result like this, i am giving example beside the table.

```
+-------+---------+----------+
| line  | type    | percent  |
+-------+---------+----------+
| EN    | x       | %100     |--> There are 3 EN and 3 ip inside the X, So 3/3=%100
| FR    | x       | %33      |
| CH    | y       | %33      |
| PT    | y       | %66      |
| EN    | y       | %33      |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

So, i try but i couldn't reach that resul in sql.

Comment: Please add what you tried. `group by line, type` is probably a starting place

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Why primary key is important for this situation

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,line CHAR(2) NOT NULL
,type CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,ip INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (line,type,ip) VALUES
('EN','x',1),
('FR','x',1),
('EN','x',2),
('EN','x',5),
('CH','y',3),
('PT','y',3),
('PT','y',4),
('EN','y',6);

SELECT line, type, COUNT(*) line_count FROM my_table GROUP BY line,type;
+------+------+------------+
| line | type | line_count |
+------+------+------------+
| CH   | y    |          1 |
| EN   | x    |          3 |
| EN   | y    |          1 |
| FR   | x    |          1 |
| PT   | y    |          2 |
+------+------+------------+

SELECT type, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) ip_count FROM my_table GROUP BY type;
+------+----------+
| type | ip_count |
+------+----------+
| x    |        3 |
| y    |        3 |
+------+----------+
```

And then combining the above...

```
SELECT a.line
     , a.type 
     , a.line_count/b.ip_count * 100 pct
  FROM
     ( SELECT line, type, COUNT(*) line_count FROM my_table GROUP BY line,type) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT type, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) ip_count FROM my_table GROUP BY type) b
    ON b.type = a.type;
    
+------+------+----------+
| line | type | pct      |
+------+------+----------+
| CH   | y    |  33.3333 |
| EN   | x    | 100.0000 |
| EN   | y    |  33.3333 |
| FR   | x    |  33.3333 |
| PT   | y    |  66.6667 |
+------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql aggregation functions can use only one grouping during single query. So you can't calculate percentage from you raw data since you need total amount of rows with line X and amount of rows per line and type simultaneously.

What you can do is leverage temporary table, where you will perform first grouping and calculate amount of rows per line:

```sql
create temporary table test_total
select line, count(*) as total
from test
group by line
```

Then you can join this table in the second query:

```sql
select t.line, t.type, count(*), tt.total, round(count(*)/tt.total * 100,2)
from test t
join test_total as tt on tt.line = t.line
group by t.line, t.type
```

Comment: Or just do it all in one query